# How to display transparent images in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a **Transparent Image** which I am trying to display using react-native's `Image` Component but the Image is being displayed with a **White Background**.

Below is my code:

```
export default class DefaultCard extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    console.log(this.props.card.logo)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlipCard style={styles.card}
          flipHorizontal={true}
          flipVertical={false}
          flip={false}
          friction={40}
          perspective={1000}
      >
          <View style={styles.face}>
            <Image source={{uri : this.props.card.logo}} style={styles.logo}/> // this.props.card.logo is a transparent Image
            <Text style={styles.companyName}>{this.props.card.companyName.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.tagLine}>{this.props.card.tagLine}</Text>
            <View style={styles.fdBottom}></View>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.back}>
            <View style={styles.bdTop}>
              <Text style={styles.fullName}>{this.props.card.fullName.toUpperCase()}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.tagLine}>{this.props.card.position}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.details}>{this.props.card.phoneNumber}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.details}>{this.props.card.email}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.details}>{this.props.card.website}</Text>
            </View>

          </View>
      </FlipCard>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  card: {
    maxHeight:200,
    maxWidth:300,
    borderColor: '#00000000',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  face: {
    height:200,
    width:300,
    borderColor: '#00000000',
    backgroundColor: '#212121',
  },
  back: {
    height:200,
    width:300,
    backgroundColor: '#4CD4E4',
  },
  fdBottom: {
    height:36,
    backgroundColor: '#4CD4E4',
    borderColor: '#00000000',
    marginTop: 25,
  },
  companyName:{
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: 22,
    marginTop: 15,
    alignSelf:'center',
    letterSpacing: 5
 },
  bdTop: {
    height: 80,
    backgroundColor: '#212121',
  },
  logo: {
      marginTop:30,
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      alignSelf: 'center',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  tagLine: {
    marginTop: 5,
    alignSelf:'center',
    color: '#4CD4E4',
    fontSize: 10,
    letterSpacing: 2,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  fullName: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginTop: 20,
    alignSelf:'center',
    letterSpacing: 5
  },
  details: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontSize: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    letterSpacing: 2,
    marginTop: 3,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  detailsContainer: {
    marginTop: 30,
  }
});
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doning wrong?

Comment: Could I see what kind of image u mentioned?

Comment: http://practicinganthropology.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/napa-mark-transparent-860x860.png. Thats the image I am trying to display but the url is different as its stored in firebase storage

Comment: have you tried giving your image opacity in styling? seems that may work

Answer (score 0):

> You have problem with your Security Image source with Apple.

If you are using HTTP connection and not https don't forget to add this
App Transport Security Settings as dictionary and into it  Allow Arbitrary Loads as Boolean with value YES like in the below figure.

> Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

> Or you can edit it in XCode

[image]